# Grouping a queryset by another related model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(TransitLine, related_name='stops')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    approved_ts = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class TransitLine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And I have a queryset:

```
Stop.objects.filter(approved_ts__isnull=False)
```

However, when I send the results of this query to the template, I want it grouped by `TransitLine`. How would I approach this?

For clarification, in the end, I want the template to look something like this:

```
<ul>
{% for tl in transit_line_list %}
 <li>
  {{ tl.name }}: 
  {% for s in tl.stops.all %}
    {{ s.name }}
  {% endfor %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, you can use [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) ...

You must order them by TransitLine, while you filter the  queryset using

```
Stop.objects.filter(approved_ts__isnull=False).order_by('line')
```

You can check the documentation...

Comment: I'll try that when I get home tonight. Thank you! Makes sense that it's template logic.

Comment: If you have any quesstions or problems, i can explain the usage with a simple example. Its easy and useful.

Comment: Thanks @FallenAngel. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should really just give the template a queryset of `TranslitLine`s. Rather than creating a queryset of `Stop`s, add an `approved_stops()` method to your `TransitLine` class like this:

```
class TransitLine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def approved_stops(self):
        return self.stops.filter(approved_ts__isnull=False)
```

Then add `'transit_line_list': TransitLine.objects.all()` to the template's context and change `{% for s in tl.stops.all %}` in the template to `{% for s in tl.approved_stops.all %}`.

Comment: That is how I left it last night. The problem is, I will get TransitLines that have no approved stops. It isn't the end of the world since I could use a conditional to prevent that TransitLine from being shown but thought there might be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
TransitLine.objects.filter(stops__in=Stops.objects.filter(approved_ts=True)).distinct().order_by('name')
```

This query selects only the lines that have approved stops.

JFYI: to find lines that have any stops, do

```
TransitLine.objects.exclude(stops__id=None).order_by('name')
```